# Form Validation set checkbox not working

Tags: php, forms, codeigniter, validation, checkbox

I've run into a problem and I don't know where its coming from:
Codeigniter 3.1.2

This is my code:

```
$this->form_validation->set_rules("fielda", "Field A", "");
$_POST["fielda"] = "valuea";
var_dump(set_checkbox("fielda", "valuea"));
var_dump(set_radio("fielda", "valuea"));
var_dump(set_select("fielda", "valuea"));
var_dump(set_value("fielda", "valuea"));
```

This is the result:

```
string(0) "" 
string(0) "" 
string(20) " selected="selected"" 
string(6) "valuea"
```

Why is the set_checkbox and set_radio returning an empty string?

side note: This is only the test scenario for better understanding and not the final code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

2 reasons why:

1. Because it checks if the actual request method is POST, not just the `$_POST` array.
2. When you use the Form Validation library, the helpers will also use it for fields that you've set validation rules for, and you modify `$_POST` *after* `set_rules()`, at which point the library has already determined that the field wasn't submit. (this doesn't really come into effect here as your `set_rules()` call doesn't contain any rules and is ignored)

Submit the form for real and it will work. A proper way to emulate that would be this:

```
$input = array("fielda" => "valuea");
$this->form_validation->set_data($input);
$this->form_validation->set_rules("fielda", "Field A", "alpha");
$this->form_validation->run();
var_dump(set_checkbox("fielda", "valuea")); // will now output "valuea"
```

Comment: Thank you for your help. Your answer seems to be legit, but even if you copy paste your suggestion, var_dump returns a zero string.

Comment: Indeed, you also have to run the validation ... updated the answer.

Comment: Damnit, thats it :) Thank you very much

Answer (score 0):

use third parameter for checkbox or radio button like

```
var_dump(set_checkbox("fielda", "valuea",TRUE));
```

Comment: If the third parameter is TRUE, the checkbox will be checked if no related data was submitted. But in my case the data was submitted but not recognized by the set_checkbox() function.